# Online whiteboard

Tags: web-apps, whiteboard

I am looking for a collaborative online whiteboard like https://awwapp.com/ with the following feature:

If I insert an image (for example a jpg file), and draw on it, I want to be able to erase my drawing/notes on the image without erasing the image (or parts of it) itself.

It should also be possible that multiple users could draw at the same time and that you could see the mouse pointers of other users such that they could point on objects using the mouse pointer for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in making precise drawings, [Microsoft Whiteboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-whiteboard/digital-whiteboard-app)  would be a good choice for you. It includes all the features you are looking for (inserting images, moving them, drawing on them, erasing drawn elements without erasing the image, multiple users, drawing at the same time...). Besides, it is free :)